# please explain how you use the city calendar

Tags: catan-cities-and-knights

We have only played settlers and got the cities and knights expansion.. there are ships on the trade calendar. . We have no ships. In settlers, you still use those items not sell them back. How do I get a ship and use it so I can buy a market. What do I do to flip the science flip? Get a knoght, promote, and activate? There is no explication at all in the rules and it frustrates us to no end.. please for the love of all help

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are missing the separate rules book for Cities and Knights. You might want to take a look [here](http://www.catan.com/service/game-rules) to download a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The ships are used only if you are combining C&K with Seafarers, if you are just playing C&K you just ignore them.

To flip any of the sections of the flip-boards you need a certain amount of the appropriate commodity (book for green,  linen for yellow, and coin for blue) it shows how many of the commodity you need at the bottom of the top half of the board.

Answer (score 0):

The flip book is only divided based on the commodity it takes to flip the page. They are color coded: Blue for the Coin commodity, Green for the Paper commodity, and Yellow for the Cloth commodity. It takes one Coin to flip the blue page for the first time, then two coin the second time, etc. The same goes for the other colors. Each of these "flips" allows you better odds of drawing a progress card that corresponds to that color. Using the red die as the indicator. After paying one Coin to flip the blue card for the first time, if a blue is rolled on the action die and either a one or a two on the *red die only* then you draw a blue progress card.

Hope this helps